# Как удалить .net 8.0, установленный скриптом с сайта Майкрософт на Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: .net

Установил, а удалить теперь вручную остерегаюсь.

Comment: Ну вроде в официальной документации всё написано же? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-linux#scripted-or-manual

Comment: Да, написано для Windows и macOS https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab/releases